# How do you make save the contents of a vector?

Tags: database, vector

So, to be even more specific. I am making a program that contains a database of cars (models, years, horsepower, etc). Of course every time i compile, obviously, the contents are reseted and the vector is empty. Is there any way to save the contents of the vector within the program without the involvements of saving it to a text file? Sorry for the stupidity of this question...I am a noob.

Comment: Well, where _do_ you want to save it? I mean, it would have to be somewhere on some hard drive if you want it to survive a reboot... You can, of course, go through some intermediaries like a database server, but in the end it will still end up in some file on some hard drive.

Comment: So, do you have some method in mind which would end up saving it in a file on a hard drive? There are multiple to choose from...

Comment: (Also, is this about C or C++? Or some other language?)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are working in c++, so you can use **MySQL Connector/C++** to save your vector data in MySQL rows for this refer to : [MySQL Connector/C++ 8.0 Developer Guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/8.0/en/) or [mysql-connector-cpp](http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/tech-resources/articles/mysql-connector-cpp.html) but this will not be simple to implement.

Else, you can save it in csv or text file and then use **python scripting** which will be very easy to implement. [MySQL Connector/Python](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/) or [Python MySQL](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_getstarted.asp)
Also if you are comfortable with **shell scripts** you can automate it all, and it will take care of all the storage stuffs.